# Applying 'data-title' to Kendo UI Grid TDs?

Tags: kendo-ui, html-table, kendo-grid

I'm using a KendoUI Grid and it's great, but it doesn't respond well on mobile devices so I'm looking to implement this [responsive data table idea](http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/). It basically hides the header, makes all cells display:block to they stack, then create a faux header to the left of the td with `td:before{content:"td header title"}`.

The only thing is, this will apply to many different tables with unknown thead fields, so I can't do

```
td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "First Name"; }
td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "Last Name"; }
td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "Job Title"; }
etc
```

Ideally, I'll apply the header column title to the TDs, so that it would render `<td data-title="headerTitle">data</td>`. Then in the CSS, I can do:

```
td:before { content: attr(data-title); }
```

That would work perfectly, but I'm not sure it's possible. Maybe someone else has other ideas.

[JS Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/TpJyu/2/)

Ex: `<td data-title="name">Jane</td>`

**EDIT:** It looks like I'm going to go with a jQuery solution:

```
function tableResizer() {
    var headerTitleArray = [];

    // create array of table header titles
    $('.k-grid-header-wrap th').each(function () {
        headerTitleArray.push($(this).attr('data-title'));
    });

    // append tables headers to each td
    $('.k-grid-content tr').each(function () {
        $(this).find('td').each(function (i) {
            if (typeof headerTitleArray[i] !== 'undefined') { // some headers don't have a title
                $(this).prepend('<span class="td-title">' + headerTitleArray[i] + '</span>');
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should rather do that with javascript, for example :

```
$("td").each(function() {
    $(this).prepend("<span class='before'>" + $(this).data('title') + "</span>");
});
```

and with class `before` styled as your `td:before`...

See this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/TpJyu/4/

Comment: Thanks man. Unfortunately it's more complicated than that because Kendo generates the table from the server data and it doesn't add data-title to the TD like that. That's what I'd love to figure out.

So it looks like I'm going to jQuery way, but it's a little more complex than this. I'll post the code in my post above.

Comment: @dmathisen I have seen your edit and your solution is fine... Just be careful with the classes names : they begin with a `t-` here (instead of a `k-`...) and you should also style `.td-title` as your `td:before`. See this working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/TpJyu/6/.

Comment: Thanks man. Seems to be working well now.
What I'm ending up doing is calling the tableResizer function and doing an 'addClass('compressed')' within that function. So on window resize, it checks for size and adds/removes that 'compressed' class as necessary. Seems more complex than it needs to be, but it works.

Thanks for taking a look!